# Polynomial is irreducible (gcd/field extension)

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

> Let $K \subset L$ be a finite field extension and $f(x) \in K[x]$ a monic and irreducible polynomial.
>
> Also, $\gcd(\deg f(x),[L:K])=1$.
>
> How to prove that $f(x)$ is irreducible in $L[x]$?

My idea was to show that $L \subset \overline{K}$.

Then I want to consider $K \subset L \subset L(a)$ and $K \subset K(a) \subset L(a)$ to find a root $a \in \overline{K}$ of $f(x)$ to show that $f(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $L$.

But I have some trouble to show it.

I tried this:

Since $K \subset L$ is finite, it implies that $[L:K] < \infty$.

So $L \subset \overline{K}=\lbrace a \in L | a$ is algebraic over $K \rbrace$, as all polynomials of $L$ have roots in $K$.

I'm not sure if this is right. And how to continue?

Comment: do you assume also that $f$ is separable ?

Comment: No, the assumption is not given.

Comment: Does it help if we assume $L=K(b)$?